# Does light comeback again?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light

I know light follow the space time curvature.I listen about gravity lensing.Is there any proof of total reflection of light due to gravity  like total internal reflection of light? If this possible what is the characteristics of mass configuration?In this situation how can I measure the position of  source and reflector?
If this possible then we get two coherent source of light which producing interference. Is this kind data really exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Light follow geodesic in spacetime geometry. If we consider a photon propagating in gravity only then the notion of refraction and reflection do not make any sense. Bending of light doesn't mean refraction. Still if you choose to call it, light going around a spacetime singularity and bending back to the observer can be called reflection.

Comment: Do have any experimental proof of it?how can someone be sure that the light bending back towards us?

Comment: @baponkar  the gravitational interaction is too weak, we can only observe bending around large masses .https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens It is not possible to create an experiment even for small lensing, let alone around a gravitational mass.

Answer (score 1):

Reflection happens when light encounters a boundary between two media. It is a result of the light being absorbed and re-emitted, the direction being due to interference between the incident light and the outgoing. Gravity bends the space through which light travels, but it doesn't absorb and re-emit light, so it can't create reflection in the usual sense of the word.

Comment: Okay suppose I am getting light two ways from directly and others from different ways by following geodesic .Now must be they produced interference to mine due to path difference.I just want to know is there any experimental paper or proof of such kind.